# How to add --minimal-main-dex argument to the dx

Tags: bazel

how to make the main dex to contains exactly classes that I have provide. ie, how to pass the `--minimal-main-dex` argument to the dx? I try to add `main_dex_list_opts = ["--minimal-main-dex"]` to the `android_binary` rule, but it doesn't work. Thanks very much for any help!

My `android_binary` rule:

```
android_binary(
    name="apk",
    custom_package = "com.xtbc",
    manifest_merger = "android",
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["res/**"], exclude=["res/.DS_Store"]),
    assets = glob(["assets/**"], exclude=["assets/.DS_Store"]),
    assets_dir = "assets",
    multidex = "manual_main_dex",
    main_dex_list = "mainDexClassList.txt",
    main_dex_list_opts = ["--minimal-main-dex"],
    dexopts = [
        "--force-jumbo"
    ],
    deps = [
        ":lib"
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dexopts` attribute of `android_binary` can be used to pass flags to `dx`. See the documentation here: https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/android.html#android_binary.dexopts

So you can use `dexopts = ["--minimal-main-dex"]`.